# Providing flight instruction on a "N" aircraft towards an EASA license in Europe

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, regulations

I need some help getting clarification on the following:

I hold a **Dutch EASA CPL** licence with **instrument rating and FI privileges**. I also hold **FAA PPL with Instrument rating** based my foreign (Dutch) Licence. I realise that FAR 61.3 allows me to excersise the privileges of my Dutch License on "N" aircraft within the boundries of the Netherlands.

If I were to be training a student towards an EASA Instrument rating, on an "N" registered aircraft and would venture into, say, Germany. Would this be permitted by FAA regulations (never mind the european rules).

I am in doubt since I would be pilot in command with appropriate FAA privileges (PPL(A) with IR). And although I am providing training, I am not providing training towards an FAA rating (FAR 61.3.d.2) so I would not be acting as an instructor in that sense.

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. Refer to 14 CFR § 61.3(d)(3)(v):

> A flight instructor certificate issued under this part is not necessary [...] Under paragraph (d)(2)(iii) of this section, if the training is given by an authorized flight instructor under § 61.41 of this part.

Then refer to § 61.41(a)(2):

> A person may credit flight training toward the requirements of a pilot certificate or rating issued under this part, if that person received the training from [...] A flight instructor who is authorized to give such training by the licensing authority of a foreign contracting State to the Convention on International Civil Aviation, and the flight training is given outside the United States.

Assuming you are authorized to give flight instruction under European rules, you can do it in a US civil aircraft. You just can't give any FAA endorsements besides that training was given. So no endorsing a student to take a practical or for solo flight, for instance. But you can endorse their logbook to show that training was given, and they can use that towards an FAA certificate or rating if they like.